# Trying to get output in the json format using json_encode() in php

Tags: php, json, associative-array, php-7

I'm trying to get output as:

```
{
   "1":{
      "word":"Apple",
      "definition":"This is a Fruit"
   },
   "2":{
      "word":"Grapes",
      "definition":"This is a Fruit too"
   },
   .
   . //so on
   .

}
```

my php7 source code(**main.php**) is :

```
<?php
require 'configure.php';

$query = "SELECT * from entries where word LIKE 'Z%'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$marks = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $marks[] =  array($row['sN'] => array(
        "word" => $row['word'],
        "definition" => $row['definition']
    ));     
}

var_dump(json_encode($marks));//(json_encode($marks));

/* free result set */
$result->free();

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

the code given below generates my desired output:

```
$marks = array(
"mohammad" => array
(
"physics" => 35,
"maths" => 30,
"chemistry" => 39
),
"qadir" => array
(
"physics" => 30,
"maths" => 32,
"chemistry" => 29
),
"zara" => array
(
"physics" => 31,
"maths" => 22,
"chemistry" => 39
)
);
echo json_encode($marks);
```

I'm trying to apply the concept of associative arrays in my **main.php**
how can I get the desired json output by using LOOP in my above **main.php**?

Comment: what is the output of `json_encode($marks)` ? and what you are expect to get ?

Comment: {"mohammad":{"physics":35,"maths":30,"chemistry":39},"qadir":{"physics":30,"maths":32,"chemistry":29},"zara":{"physics":31,"maths":22,"chemistry":39}}

Comment: I expect to get the above output..!

Comment: what's your output of `json_encode($marks)` ? how could you define some thing in your array - word and definition - and expect something other -physics ,maths and chemistry- ?

Comment: @HassanAhmed, I have pasted two codes:
One is of main.PHP where I want to get the output in JSON format and other one is code I copied from a tutorial (consisting of physics chemistry and maths). Just Forget about the values. I just want them to be of the format I posted very above of my Question.
LIKE 
{
   "1":{
      "word":"Apple",
      "definition":"This is a Fruit"
   },
   "2":{
      "word":"Grapes",
      "definition":"This is a Fruit too"
   },
   .
   . //so on
   .

}

Answer (score 0):

Try once using `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` as parameter of `json_encode()` function. like this..

```
echo json_encode($marks,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

> **JSON_FORCE_OBJECT**:Outputs an object rather than an array when a non-associative array is used. Especially useful when the recipient of the output is expecting an object and the array is empty.

Comment: what you get in `var_dump(json_encode($marks,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));`.

Comment: I get 
bool(false)

Comment: if I 
replace 
$marks[ ] =  array($row['sN'] => array("word"=>$row['word'],
    "definition"=>$row['definition']
   ));
by 
$marks =  array($row['sN'] => array("word"=>$row['word'],
    "definition"=>$row['definition']
   ));  

I get: {"176023":{"word":"Zythum","definition":"A kind of ancient malt beverage; a liquor made from malt\n and wheat."}}

this is What is want . Now how can I get other values

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in how you are assign your `$marks` array

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $marks[$row['sN']] = array(
        "word" => $row['word'],
        "definition" => $row['definition']
    );     
}
```

and to get 0 indexed array you may

```
$index = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $marks[$index] = array(
        "word" => $row['word'],
        "definition" => $row['definition']
    );
    $index++;
}
```

Comment: it generates bool(false)

Comment: if I replace $marks[ ] = array($row['sN'] => array("word"=>$row['word'], "definition"=>$row['definition'] )); by $marks = array($row['sN'] => array("word"=>$row['word'], "definition"=>$row['definition'] )); I get: {"176023":{"word":"Zythum","definition":"A kind of ancient malt beverage; a liquor made from malt\n and wheat."}} this is What is want . Now how can I get other values ?

Comment: well , remove `$row['sN']` from your code to be `$marks[]`, check my edit

Comment: Generates the output in Json format but only the last row is saved into the variable $marks

Comment: bool(false)....

try replacing "$marks[$index]" by "$marks" it works but only last row is saved in $marks. I think we have to deal with conversion of arrays into objects.

Comment: Okay iam checking out that In the mean time I've tried the reverse 
$json = '{
   "1":{
      "word":"Apple",
      "definition":"This is a Fruit"
   },
   "2":{
      "word":"Grapes",
      "definition":"This is a Fruit too"
   }
}';
  var_dump(json_decode($json)); 
It generates the Output:
stdClass Object ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [word] => Apple [definition] => This is a Fruit ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [word] => Grapes [definition] => This is a Fruit too ) )

Comment: its not working because of how I'm fetching data from the database.
checkout at https://3v4l.org/9cQKP

Comment: $marks[] = array(
        "word" => $row['word'],
        "definition" => $row['definition']
    ); 


return's  bool(false)

Comment: Here is the output:https://expirebox.com/download/69439b8ec38e50c02899c68e3f1aa081.html

by the way can I get email so that in the evening I could send you the link of the project on GITHUB